# How to logout from all open tab once I i logout from one tab in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, single-page-application, logout

Gwt is single page application. I have issue. if I am logged-in in different tabs and if I logout from any of one tab. other tab still works. but if I refresh than it does log out. 
my understanding is gwt is single page application and it does not refresh the page. it only clear the panel and put new stuff on that same panel. if I refresh the page it goes back to the main page 
My question is : How can I check if I am already log out without refreshing the page? 
any suggestion adn help would be appreciated

I tried the Window.Location.reload(); but this load the page and I go back to the main page

if I log out than it should logout from all other tabs and go back to the login page

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s normally enough to leave the other tabs as they are, and as soon as the user tries to do something involving a server connection, which will fail once the user is logged out, redirect the user to a login page then.

However, if you want the user to be logged out immediately, you need to make a server call (e.g. GWT-RPC) regularly to check that the user is still logged in. For example, once every 5 seconds. For example, you could schedule such a repeating check using http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFixedDelay-com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand-int-

Comment: I have added the Value change handler. which stores the history of browser. adn it worked perfectly the way I wanted to